# How to get started with using Python for animal tracking?

Tags: python, python-3.x, video, tracking

I am using Python 3.X on macOS Sierra, and want to write a Python programme that should be able to: (1) load a 1 min video (format probably .avi), (2) identify white larvae (I am a biologist working on fly larvae) on a dark-ish background, (3) track the flies over the 1 min, and (4) output a .csv file with x- and y-coordinates for each larvae.

Now, what I am asking is not for anyone to write the code, I want to do that myself; rather, since I am totally new to working with videos, and only have marginal Python experience, it would help me for people to suggest a strategy I could follow to write that programme, such as specific modules that contain functions useful for this task, etc.